# sort redis records by a certain value

Tags: redis

I have a redis table where values are stored like

```
key: "aa - 1" value {"price": "10"}
key: "aa - 2" value {"price": "8"}
key: "aa - 4" value {"price": "15"}
```

I am executing `keys *aa*` to get the list of keys. Is there a way to get this list ordered by the `price` as well? 
thanks.

Comment: What do you have there, actually? There's no such a thing as a table in redis. You probably have a db with some keys. What type are your keys?

Comment: Yes I have a db with keys. The keys are just strings, and the values are JSON objects.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the type of the values (keys are always strings). json is not a redis data type; however I added my answer

Answer (score 0):

Redis is not very complex. It is for sure not document based, and doesn't have a json type.

From your comment I understand that you saved json within strings. There's no way to sort that.

[Here](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) is an overview of redis types: if you need sorting, you should decide for [sorted sets](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#sorted-sets), with price as score.

Answer (score 0):

First of all this is not a table actually. You should consider your data as a set of objects which you can identify by key: you put your object with key1 and can get it back quickly using key. But your object is simply string or even byte[].

To store data in key-value storage many ways can be used. You can put whole object into the key and always get back whole object. No way to sort anything.
You may also to do some kind of vertical split on property level, and store each property or sub-object separately. Something like:

```
key: "aa - 1:price" value "10"
key: "aa - 1:name" value "CoolName"
```

Obvious drawback - it is hard to maintain in consistent way, you need many requests to get whole objects. Though `GET "aa - 1:*"` can be used as well

But as positive thing here, you may store different properties using different redis data structures.

For example you can store `price` using ZADD. Something like that:

```
ZADD pricesSet 10 "aa - 1"
ZADD pricesSet 4 "aa - 2"
```

Then you can use ZRANGEBYSCORE to take data from this key

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE priceSet 5 15
```

Means to get keys of all items with price from 5 to 15. You will get "aa - 1" and can then get it separately.

And YES, output of ZRANGEBYSCORE  is sorted by price.